# Windows Updates Install Over and Over

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Edit: I'm noticing updates for products that don't exist on my system. Take KB2553322. That's for InfoPath, but it's not on my system.

I recently noticed Office 2010 SP2 was failing to install. It wanted me to browse to an MSI named Pro-Plus. I noticed Pro Plus was installed on the machine at some point in the past (Standard is the current version), and found where it was being referenced. Deleting the key in the registry cleared the issue, and SP2 installed.

Then the next wave of updates installed over and over. Each update says "Update is ready for downloading", but downloads instantly. According to WU log, `* All files for update were already downloaded and are valid`. Deleting the `SoftwareDistribution` folder forces a new download, but it doesn't fix the issue.

According to Installed Updates, under Program and Features, these updates aren't listed. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\[Your SID Here]\Products` lists a few of the updates. However, one update (KB2597091) is not listed in Installed Updates or anywhere in the registry. Yet, when I try to install manually, it claims it's already installed.

Screenshot is the results of a search through the registry (location mentioned above). It is deemed installed if it mentioned anywhere. This also will give you a list of all the updates that won't install for me.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do I seriously need to explicitly define that? The same Windows Updates are installing over and over. What do you think I'm looking to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The leftover Professional Plus installation was deeper than I thought. I removed all instances of it in the registry. As soon as I did that, the inapplicable updates disappeared. The point here is inapplicable updates won't throw an error. Make sure the updates apply to your system.

Edit: I also noticed that the windowsupdate log doesn't help here. Log shows this despite the update not being required.

```
Success Content Install Installation Successful: Windows successfully installed the following update: Security Update for Microsoft InfoPath 2010 (KB2510065), 64-Bit Edition
```